# Java Manifest attribute missing

Tags: java, maven, components, vaadin, manifest

I compiled the standard vaadin "selfmade component template" with maven.

```
mvn clean install
```

When I try to upload the .zip folder in targets to the vaadin directory I get an error: "Upload failed: Missing attribute Implementation-Vendor in the manifest file of test-0.1.jar."

[image]

My java manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Vaadin-Package-Version: 1
Vaadin-Addon: test-0.1.jar
Vaadin-License-Title: Apache License 2.0
Implementation-Vendor: ${project.organization.name}
Implementation-Title: MyComponent Add-on
Implementation-Version: 0.1
```

What does ${...} mean? Is it a path variable and if yes how to set it during compilation with maven?

Comment: It's a variable that should be declared somewhere prior to this line; Can you hardcode a value and try build it again ?

Comment: I would try to set the value `<project><organization><name>` in your `pom.xml`

Comment: @JF Meier: Still same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you either have to set a value for that in your `pom.properties` file or simply just replace `${project.organization.name}` with your desired vendor in `pom.xml`. For example, it can be something like `com.cryp71x.test`.

As long as it has a value and complies with the format.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you send me the `.jar` file?

Comment: Well its a .zip file and you can create it when you have a vaadin account and go to publish a new component.

Comment: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-widget \
-DarchetypeVersion=INSERT_VAADIN_VERSION

Comment: and then mvn clean install

Comment: Sure I know the process. I develop the Directory myself :) I'm more interested in getting your `.zip` file to communicate back on what you need to do.

Comment: o.k. I can send it to you via email

Comment: You can use any file upload service online like Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. I found this one particular one where you don't need any registration, maybe try this? https://uploadfiles.io/

Comment: I have a look at `pom.xml` and there were several problems:

- `Manifest.mf` is generated automatically based on the content in `pom.xml` and editing it is a workaround way. The reason why your Implementation-Vendor was `${project.organization.name}` is because you have commented out the `organization` part (around line 30). 
- The name must be unique rather the default one `MyComponent Add-on`. This can be done easily by changing the `name` tag in `pom.xml`. We don't allow add-ons to have the same name.

After that, try re-package and publish again.